# setting layout background using picasso is not updating the background on first open

Tags: android, android-activity, background, picasso

i am setting a drawrlayout background using Picasso, and looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464867/how-to-load-layout-background-using-picasso/31464960#31464960) question and followed the steps, it works but the weird thing that is happening is that it doesn't update the background when the activity is first opened (meaning I have to close it then open it again and the background appears)

this is my layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_store"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_store_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**EDIT: after the suggestion**
and this is my activity class :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;

public class Store extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_store);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    final DrawerLayout layout = (DrawerLayout) Store.this.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    Target t = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            final Bitmap p = bitmap;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(Store.this.getResources(), p));
                }
            });
            Log.d("TAG", "Loaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
            Log.d("TAG", "FAILED");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Prepare Load");
        }
    };

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        layout.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(Store.this.getResources(), bitmap));
    }
});
```

Comment: should I add this to the activity class or the target class?

Comment: can you please tell me if the edit is correct? because it is still doing the same thing

Comment: Replace this line                                  layout.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(Store.this.getResources(), bitmap));      with  suggested code

Comment: I edited the code per your suggestion and it still has the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Picasso holds a weak reference to Target objects, hence it is likely to be garbage collected. So create a separate class of Target and set the data. Also you are using wrong layout for background change.

```
public class Store extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private DrawerLayout layout;
private NavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.toolbar_layout);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    layout = (DrawerLayout) Store.this.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    Picasso.with(this).load("http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/58/2e/b9/582eb968-988b-ad42-dee6-92d396cbde5c/icon256.png").into(mTarget);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return true;
}

final Target mTarget = new Target() {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "onBitmapLoaded");
        BitmapDrawable mBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
        navigationView.setBackground(mBitmapDrawable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "onBitmapFailed");
    }


    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "onPrepareLoad");
    }
};
}
```