# Android: download image from web and set as fragment background

Tags: android

With a link for an image such as www.example.com/image.png how do I download the image and set it as the background for a fragment? Would it be an imageview that is resized to the size of the content container? How do I put an image from the web to an imageview?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Load Layout Background Using Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464867/how-to-load-layout-background-using-picasso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be an ImageView to match the fragment height/width and with the property `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`. To download and show the image in that ImageView use `Glide`. Here is the official documentation.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will give this a shot!

Answer (score 1):

To make the screen occupy fullscreen, and proper scaling adds the following properties to ImageView.

```
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

When we set adjustViewBounds to true we are telling the ImageView (not the drawable) to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.
and add the scale type to imageview

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

and if get the image of same ratio passing width and height, using the thumbor libray.Here is the link for reference
https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor